# How is max size calculated in the function max_size() in std::list?

Tags: c++, list

In std::list, how is max size calculated in the function max_size()? Now I realize it is up to the implementation, but let's assume I am the one making the standard library. How would I go about determining the maximum limit for `list` of a particular type `T` that is also portable?

Comment: For what it's worth, the GNU implementation defines it as `_M_get_Node_allocator().max_size();`, which in turn returns `size_t(-1) / sizeof(_Tp);`.

Comment: However it is calculated, the value is basically worthless... the system will complain well before reaching this theoretical limit.

Comment: It's generally worhtless for `std::allocator`, which in general will try to allocate any memory that might be available on the system. Specific pool allocators exist as well, and there `max_size` will equal the pool size. You definitely can run out of such a pool, that's more than theory.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much always the maximum value of N, where the container may have up to N elements. This pretty much always means the maximum value of the unsigned integer type on the platform in question, divided by the size of the type of elements to be stored in the container.

Comment: Can you point me to the section of the C++ ISO standard that says it is max value of unsigned int type? C++. 2011 or 1998 either will do

Comment: @AdrianCornish: No, I cannot. It's implementation-defined. I said "pretty much always".

Comment: Actually it is usually the maximum unsigned integer divided by `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: @Nemo: I think it tends to consider addressing rather than element storage. So dividing by `sizeof(T*)` _would_ make sense, but still I don't believe that this is usually the case.

Comment: @Adrian: Also, are you allergic to 2003? :)

Comment: @Tomalak: It is not implementation define it is clearly defined by the c++ standard. max_size() is defined to return size_type. Which according to the language standard is "size_type can represent any non-negative value of difference_type" Please dont give bad answers using types which are not defined ie int

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Feel free to write your own competing answer if you feel that you have better information, rather than flaming people. I'd be happy to rescind my answer if you can prove that there is a standard-defined value for this quantity. (And I don't see how `max_size()` having a defined _type_ is the same as having a defined _value_...)

Comment: @Tomalak: I am not flaming people -you said return was unsigned int - I asked you to provide the section of the language standard that said this - you cannot because it is not there. Please dont make things up for c++ - this is why there is ~1000 page language standard. And maybe if you looked - I did provide an answer before correcting you.

Comment: @Adrian: I never said anything of the sort. Read my answer again.

Comment: The standard makes no comment of a max value of unsigned int type - your answer - "This pretty much always means the maximum value of the unsigned integer type on the platform in question"

Comment: @Adrian: And, as has now been stated numerous times, that's because it's _implementation-defined_. The OP is asking what decisions an implementer makes when coming up with his/her implementation-defined quantity for any given implementation; I have told the OP what that quantity usually ends up being. Just because it's an _implementation-defined_ quantity rather than well-defined in the standard, doesn't mean that the quantity magically does not exist.

Comment: But you state it is unsigned int - it is not a unsigned int - it is std::size_type - why unsigned int is implementation defined true enough - the standard does not define the return value as unsigned int. Therefore you statement is wrong.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Where did I state that it is an `unsigned int`? You're making things up.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Your language and behaviour is completely unacceptable. Please find your comment flagged. Also, if you read that quote more carefully, you'll note that in no way does it talk about the _type_ of `max_size`, only that its _value_ matches that of the maximum value of the unsigned integer type. Very different. Thanks for trying to participate in this question, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4607/discussion-between-adrian-cornish-and-tomalak-geretkal)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I have nothing further to say, especially after your profane little outburst a moment ago.

Comment: @Tomalak: I admit that I may have peeked at the libstdc++ source before posting my comment...  :-)

Comment: @Nemo: There's nothing but wisdom in that!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the STL list container uses std::allocator as an allocator object by default. And, depending on the type been passed as template argument (type), std::allocator's max_size() method will return a number that represents the maximum number of objects it can allocate of that passed type.
List should allocate memory for nodes, that's why you should pass the node struct as template argument:

```
struct node {
         int data;
         node *next;
         node *prev;
      }
std::allocator<node_struct> A;
std::cout << A.max_size();
```

, that will print the maximum number of nodes it can allocate (not the amount of bytes).

How it may be implemented:

```
namespace test {
   template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
   class list {
   private:
      struct node {
         T data;
         node *next;
         node *prev;
      }
      using node_allocator = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<node>;
      node_allocator allocator;
   //...
   public:
   //...
      void max_size() { return allocator.max_size(); }
   //...
   };
}
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Its usually something like

```
numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
```

As this is the only limit the collection imposes and not the platform. The collection is only responsible to itself so even if it can compute something like the maximum memory of the system, it will still only return the limit it imposes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the standard - this is the size of the largest possible container. The function must have constant complexity as well.

From the current C++ standard:
size_type distance(begin(), end()) for the largest possible container

Comment: What is begin() and end() in this case?